# how to use code block plugin in ckeditor5 cdn in python django?

Tags: django, codeblocks, ckeditor5

it can't work...
i cant find solution.
i used  tag, so applied cdn. and i want make code block extension in ckeditor

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/29.1.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 strong text<textarea id="editor" name="queseditor"></textarea>
 <script>
 ClassicEditor
 .create( document.querySelector('#editor'), {
 codeBlock: {
 languages: [
 { language: 'python', label: 'Python' }
 ]
 }
 } )
 .catch( error => {
 console.error( error );
 } );
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet has tag error.

This is the fixed snippet which fix your issue (you forget to close script tag) :

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/29.1.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 strong text<textarea id="editor" name="queseditor"></textarea>
 <script>
 ClassicEditor
 .create( document.querySelector('#editor'), {
 codeBlock: {
 languages: [
 { language: 'python', label: 'Python' }
 ]
 }
 } )
 .catch( error => {
 console.error( error );
 } );
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it the fact that the questioners last `</script>` tag is not indented? Besides that indent change the two snippets are identical.

Comment: With this tag everything works fine, so for me it's really the issue but fixed in question for the snippet

Comment: So, now it works fine ?

Answer (score 0):

The codeblock plugin is only available in the superbuild of ckeditor5.

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/41.1.0/super-build/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Here is a reference to this: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/predefined-builds.html#superbuild